# access return value of function from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have one js file having code as:

```
function postResponse(url1,param1)
{
var url = intranetUrl + encodeURI(url1);

 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e)
    {
        if (this.status == 200)
        {
            genericRes = this.responseText;
            console.log("inside fun:"+genericRes);
            return genericRes;
        }
        alert("!!!"+this.status);
    };

    xhr.send(param1);


}
```

Now from another file I want to access this function I had imported above file in this file and call function as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var resss = postResponse("myURL","ACC|^ALL|^M|^|$");
        alert("genericRes"+genericRes);
        console.log("genericRes>>>"+genericRes);
        console.log("resss>>>"+resss); 

    </script>
```

But here I got genericRes and resss value as undefined, and above console.log prints first and then it prints   `console.log("inside fun:"+genericRes);`  here I got correct output,  But from calling code it gives me undefined.

In java we write suppose method which can return String as:

```
public String myMethod()
{
      str = "MyString";
      return str;
}
```

and call that method as:

```
String str1 = myMethod();
```

But how to do this in jquery?

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully, you are defining another function, as in:

```
function(e) //<-- this is the another function
{
    if (this.status == 200)
    {
        var genericRes = this.responseText;
        console.log("inside fun:"+genericRes);
        return genericRes; //<-- this only applies to this function
    }
    alert("!!!"+this.status);
};
```

So it will return that value to the caller of `xhr.onload`, which is the browser and the browser doesn't do anything with the return value.

Furthermore, you cannot really return from asynchronous operations, you have to use a callback.

So:

```
function postResponse(url1, param1, callback) { // <-- take a callback parameter
    var url = intranetUrl + encodeURI(url1);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var genericRes = this.responseText;
            callback( genericRes ); // <-- call the callback
        }
    };
    xhr.send(param1);
}
```

Then in your code:

```
postResponse("myURL", "ACC|^ALL|^M|^|$", function(result) {
    alert(result); //Result is only available here. In this anonymous function defined inline. Yes.
});
```

Comment: would you mind if I ask, what the `result` would  be? `responceText` or status of the HTTP-request?

Comment: @caligula Since we are calling it like `callback( genericRes )`, `result` will be that.